# Windows 8: Choose What To Keep

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-installation

I have downloaded "Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant" from Microsoft Windows 8 Website. I am currently using Windows 7 right now.

When I run an application, I have to select one of the following option what I want to keep:

- Windows Setting, Personal Files and apps
- Just Personal Files
- Nothing

If I select **Nothing**, will Pictures and Documents will be deleted? They are located in different in drive (Eg: `E:\Pictures\`) and I have set the paths in **Pictures Properties** and **Documents Properties**

Comment: If you select **NOTHING** then all your files will be not be transferred and will be located in `Windows.old`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows Installer won't touch any drive other than the one you are installing to. So if you installing Windows on drive C, all other drives on the system will remain un-affected.

So, NO, even if you select Nothing, your Pictures and Documents located in a drive other than the one you are installing to wont be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be be safe side..... I recommend you backup your Personal Files to external hard drive, or offsite (cloud or hosting).

Remove the paths in 'Pictures Properties' and 'Documents Properties' and then install windows 8.